# How to load Rust compiler plugins without modifying the source code?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Rust provides various ways to write plugins. To extend checks on Rust code, it allows developer to write [Lint Plugins](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/compiler-plugins.html). A typical way to use the plugin is to add a line to the source code indicating the use of this plugin:

```
#![plugin(myplugin)]
```

You also need to edit the `Cargo.toml` file to include your plugin project in the `dependencies` section:

```
myplugin = {path = "/path/to/myproject"}
```

However, if you want to analyze big projects, these modifications seem to be troubling, I wonder if `cargo build` or `rustc` provides any way to load my plugins without modifying the source code.

Answer (score 3):

`rustc` has a command-line parameter for loading additional plugins: `-Z extra-plugins=<plugins>`. However, this option also requires that the path to the compiled plugin library be passed to the compiler. This is done automatically if the plugin library is declared as a dependency in Cargo.toml. If it's not in Cargo.toml, then you can compile it independently and reference it manually with `--extern my_plugin=/path/to/plugin.rlib`, in addition to the `-Z extra-plugins=<plugins>` option.

There's another option. [Clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy), a large collection of general lints for Rust, provides a program that can be invoked as `cargo clippy`. That program basically acts as a fake `rustc`, implementing a compiler frontend (using internal crates used by `rustc`) that loads Clippy directly into the compiler's plugin registry (for the main project only, not for the project's dependencies). [You can see the code on GitHub (licensed under MPLv2).](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/blob/master/src/main.rs) The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to give a path to the plugin, because the plugin is built in the frontend. This makes it very convenient to use for the plugin's users. The disadvantage is that such a program relies on unstable compiler internals. This means that your program can stop compiling at any time due to a breaking change in `rustc`'s unstable API.

Comment: Thanks, very great!